# turn positive values to negative in SQL Snowfalke

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, negative-integer

I have a column where the values describe the price of an item that has been returned. They are positive and when sum:ing them I would need them to become negative.
Ex:

| order id | item id | returned | price | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 456 | True | 50 | 1 |
| 987 | 123 | True | 10 | 2 |

Example query below to get the sum of the returned value:

```
sum(case when returned = 'True' then (price * quantity) else 0 end) as returnedAmount
```

One thought I had was:

```
sum(case when returned = 'True' then (-1*(price * quantity)) else 0 end) as returnedAmount
```

But that returned null, not sure why. Does anyone have a smarter suggestion?

Comment: Your second code is actually fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `returned` column is boolean then comparison is just column name:

```
SELECT col, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN retruned THEN -1*(price * quantity) ELSE 0 END) AS returnedAmmount 
FROM tab 
GROUP BY col;
```

If the query returns NULL it could mean that either PRICE or QUANTITY columsn are nullable for all values in a group:

```
SELECT col, 
  COALESCE(SUM(IIF(retruned, -1*(price * quantity),0)), 0) AS returnedAmmount 
FROM tab 
GROUP BY col;
```

Answer (score 1):

so you don't need to multiply by -1 you can just negate the value:

```
SELECT 
    order_id,
    sum(iff(returned,-(price * quantity), 0)) as returnedAmount
FROM VALUES
    (123,456,True,50,1),
    (987,123,True,10,2)
    t(order_id, item_id, returned, price,quantity)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

gives:

| ORDER_ID | RETURNEDAMOUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | -50 |
| 987 | -20 |

So to the null, so ether value could null and as Lukasz showed, you can fix that on the outside of the sum, there are a few options [ZEROIFNULL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/zeroifnull.html), [COALESCE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/coalesce.html), [NVL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/nvl.html), [IFNULL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/ifnull.html).

if you want the value zero, I feel zeroifnull is explicit, while the other three you have to parse the expression all the way to the right to see the alternative value.

```
SELECT 
    order_id,
    sum(iff(returned, -(price * quantity), 0)) as ret_a,
    zeroifnull(sum(iff(returned, -(price * quantity), 0))) as ret_b,
    coalesce(sum(iff(returned, -(price * quantity), 0)),0) as re_c,
    nvl(sum(iff(returned, -(price * quantity), 0)),0) as ret_d,
    ifnull(sum(iff(returned, -(price * quantity), 0)),0) as ret_e
FROM VALUES
    (123,456,True,50,1),
    (987,123,True,10,2),
    (988,123,True,null,2),
    (989,123,True,10,null),
    (989,123,True,null,null)
    t(order_id, item_id, returned, price,quantity)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

gives:

| ORDER_ID | RET_A | RET_B | RET_C | RET_D | RET_E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | -50 | -50 | -50 | -50 | -50 |
| 987 | -20 | -20 | -20 | -20 | -20 |
| 988 | null | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 989 | null | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |